# Creating folders in Gmail like Yahoo! does

Tags: gmail, yahoo-mail

Can we create folders in Gmail the same way as it happens in Yahoo!?

Gmail provides the "label" feature but Yahoo! folders easily separates the messages as categorized.

Comment: Moreover, Gmail supports nested labels allowing you also to mimic sub-folders.

Comment: Just don't apply more than one label, there you get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but you are looking for a feature that simply does not exist in gmail. You will not be able to change that behavior unless you download your e-mail to a local client like Outlook and use it to sort your mail.

http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=10708

Answer (score 6):

It really is semantics.  Labeling a message and dragging it into the label pulls it out of the inbox.  In fact, if you think "folder" instead of "label", it really works the same with the added feature that a message can appear in two folders at once.

Loosen your brain and let it work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use labels quite like folders if you prefer.

For instance, you can drag and drop your emails to labels.

Read more of "[Labels: drag and drop, hiding, and more](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/07/labels-drag-and-drop-hiding-and-more.html)" at the Official Gmail Blog.